# Confirm URL using POM Nightwatch

Tags: selenium, nightwatch.js, pageobjects

New to nightwatch and js in general and I'm struggling to figure out how to validate a url using pom pattern. I know this is wrong. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated, including useful links for me to rtfm as I'm struggling to find robust examples of pom nightwatch.

test.js

```
module.exports = {
    "tags": ['sanity'],
    'confirm navigation to example.com' : function (client) {
        var landingPage = client.page.landing();
        landingPage.navigate();
        landingPage.confirmOnLandingPage();
        client.end();
    }
};
```

page.js

```
var landingCommands = {
    navigate:function(){
        url: 'example.com/'
    },

    confirmOnLandingPage:function(){
        this.expect.element('body')
        .to.be.present.before(1000)
        .url(function(result) 
        {
            this.assert.equal(result.value, 'example.com/', 'On Landing Page.')
        });
    }
}
```

> Running:  confirm navigation to example.com
>   ✖ TypeError:
>   this.expect.element(...).to.be.present.before(...).url is not a
>   function
>   at Page.confirmOnLandingPage (/Users/Home/Development/NWQA/pages/page.js:9:10)
>       at Object.confirm navigation to example.com (/Users/Home/Development/NWQA/tests/test.js:7:21)
>
> FAILED:  1 errors (18ms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After running `.expect` you break the Nightwatch command chain and start Expect.js chain so after you call `this.expect.element('body').to.be.present.before(1000)` you get Expect.js object and not Nightwatch browser object.

To fix just start a new chain and change `this.url` call to `this.api.url` since `url()` is not available within the page object:

```
confirmOnLandingPage: function(){
    this.expect.element('body').to.be.present.before(1000);

    this.api.url(function(result) 
    {
        this.assert.equal(result.value, 'example.com/', 'On Landing Page.')
    });
}
```

**Update:**

I just noticed you incorrectly declared URL for your page object. `navigate` is internal function, you only need to provide `url` property:

```
var landingCommands = {
    url: 'example.com/',

    ...
};
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried this exact method and received *TypeError: this.url is not a function

Comment: @LoflinA Looks like `.url()` command is not available within page object. Try `this.api.url()` instead. `this.api` should point to `client` instance

Comment: getting close with this latest suggestion. now I'm seeing Failed [equal]: (On Landing Page.)  - expected "example.com/" but got: "data:,"

Comment: thinking this may just be the page not loading yet. will try adding a waitForElementVisable or something to wait for the page to load and report back.

Comment: @LoflinA take a look at my update to the post. The page probably is not being loaded at all